Long boot time, blank or garbled screen until login screen- Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
I am experiencing long boot times on my Ubuntu Desktop (>5min.) and during boot there is either no output to my monitors (dual, DP) or there is a stream of scrolling horizontal static. Finally the login screen will appear as normal. I log in and there are never any issues with the display after that.
VGA compatible controller:  NVIDIA Corporation GA102GL [RTX A4500]
Driver Version : 535.113.01
I've looked at so many other posts but can't find the same scenario. I checked the boot log and there are a number of warnings/errors. Like these:
May 30 09:46:15 kernel: You have booted with nomodeset. This means your GPU drivers are DISABLED
May 30 09:46:15 kernel: Any video related functionality will be severely degraded, and you may not even be able to suspend the system properly
May 30 09:46:15 kernel: Unless you actually understand what nomodeset does, you should reboot without enabling it

May 30 09:46:15 kernel: nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
May 30 09:46:15 kernel: nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
May 30 09:46:15 kernel: Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint

And the top processes contributing to the boot delay are:
>systemd-analyze blame
 2min 37ms systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
1min 392ms apt-daily-upgrade.service
   15.082s fstrim.service
    9.107s plocate-updatedb.service
    6.348s snap.lxd.activate.service
    6.141s snapd.service
    5.732s NetworkManager-wait-online.service

But this is my first Linux machine (or any machine). What settings and other logs should I check? I'm afraid of doing something that will cause it to not boot at all. Because otherwise it is working fine.

FYI:  If you're still running Ubuntu 22.04.3 then you're behind on applying security fixes and other updates..  The release is 22.04 (ie. 2022-April release) with the .3 giving details if its install media, OR what upgrades have been applied if an installed system.  This page (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/02/22/ubuntu-22-04-4-lts-released/) shows the ISO release date of 22.04.4, however installed systems upgraded before that date, so your details (if accurate) show you're not applying security fixes - apply them & try again.  Work out why you're not applying fixes.

I am intentionally not upgrading because this system is essentially a small server and upgrading could cause my drivers to stop working. There is never anything wrong with the display once I get to the Ubuntu login screen. Is this something silly like an incompatible screen resolution during boot, maybe?
